# Is there any way to express a constant matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let's say we have

$P=A+V+r(A+V)$

where $r$ is an independent variable, $A$ is a variale matrix and $V$ is a constant matrix. Is there any expression that allows me to express that $V$ is an constant matrix?

Comment: Define $f_V(A, r) = P$ ?

Comment: Constants are usually denoted using the first letters of the Latin alphabet. Variables are usually denoted using the last letters of the Latin alphabet.

Comment: krirkrirk, sorry I can't understand. Could you please explain that function?

Comment: V is supposed to be constant with respect to what?

Comment: constant with respect to P. In other words, no matter how much P changes, V will be the same.

Comment: $P(A,r) = A+V+r(A+V)$ i.e. write $P$ as a function of $A$ and $r$ but not $V$. I also like the other comment's suggestion to use $P_V(A,r)$ instead, which suggests that $V$ is a fixed parameter on which $P$ depends, whereas the other symbols are variables.